# Bug? Programmatically added content not shown in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have some strange behavior with the content of a fragment.
I created an app with swipeable tab menu, total 4 fragments/tabs.

On the fourth fragment, i add content (TextViews) programmatically, according to 2 spinner on the top of the fragment. So when you choose a value of one of the spinner, the content (inside a LinearLayout) is being replaced with new generated TextViews.

Everything is working nice, BUT:
When both spinner are on the first value (and just there), the content disapears when i swipe to another fragment and come back to the fourth fragment. After selecting another value from one of the spinners, the content is being generated as normal, also when i select the first values again.
When i swipe the first time to the fourth fragment, i see the content.

Any hint?

Comment: please post some code in order to help you better..

Comment: What Code do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your states of the fragments are not saved correctly.
Try setting:

```
myViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats it! Thank you, sir :)

Comment: Your very welcome. Can u accept the answer then? I'm trying to make some points today :)

Comment: Sure, i had to wait :)